# Using Gradle multi-project build apply plugin is applicable to master project

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

In a multi-project build using Gradle v5.5.1 I am trying to apply the `ear` plugin only to certain subprojects (as described in [using plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl)).  You can see here that I'm trying to apply it for subprojects ending in `EAR`:

```
subprojects { Project proj ->
  afterEvaluate { 
    if(proj.projectDir.name.endsWith('EAR')){
      logger.debug "{} looks like an EAR subproject", proj.name
      apply plugin: 'ear'
      defaultTasks 'ear'
    }
}
```

However, it applies it to my `master` project instead (output log):

```
10:53:36.366 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] MAG820PAYMENTRECONEAR looks like an EAR subproject
10:53:36.367 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Apply plugin org.gradle.ear to root project 'master'' started
```

Then when it gets to the execution of my subproject it says the `ear` task is not found:

```
10:53:36.375 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Task 'ear' not found in project ':MAG820PAYMENTRECON:MAG820PAYMENTRECONEAR'.
```

I know this works because I have other projects doing similar but I can't figure out why this one is working this way.

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Use `proj.apply`

Comment: That's it..!  I had just tried that and was coming back to answer the question as you indicated.  If you record it as an answer I'll acknowledge.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `proj.apply plugin: 'ear'` to call the method on the sub-project